# Special Query: Title, Terms, Content - %LIKE%

Tags: posts, customization, taxonomy, query, sql

I'm working on a them  theme that is search-heavy, and my users are putting huge priority on an improved search function.

I think I will have to use a special direct query to search these things:

1. Terms
2. Title
3. Content

And allow flexibility such as:

1. Word fragments (search **bread**, finds **wonderbread**)
2. Phrases (search Orange Man, returns post with **man** in title, **orange** in terms)

Without asking anyone to re-invent the wheel, **I was wondering if any such direct query example existed that I can modify to the needs of my custom post type** (and possibly taxonomy).

I have no doubt many have wondered the same thing in various projects.

Comment: You start off talking about a theme, and then ask about a custom post type, which you haven't described. Regardless, this question is, at core, an SQL one.

Comment: You could always go the route of an out-of-the-box solution, with a plugin I've had great results with this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/